# I get an exception when I try to delete a register that not exists in the database

Tags: entity-framework, concurrency

I am doing some tests with concurrency and Entity Framework 4.0. I am doing the following, with two users:

The user 1 load the registers.
The user 2 load the registers.
The user 2 delete one register.
The user 1 try to delete the same register that have been delete by the client 2.

The code that I use is the following:

```
using(Context myContext = new Context))
{
Users myUser = new Users { IDUser = paramUser.IDUser };
myContext.Users.Attach(myUser);
myContext.Users.DeleteObject(myUser);
miContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

When the user 1 try to delete the register, get the following exception: "Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. Refresh ObjectStateManager entries".

I know that this is a problem of concurrency, but I have the idea that the default behavior of EF is apply the changes always. If I set concurrency control the compare if there is changes between my grabbed data and the update. But in this case, all of the properties of my entities have the concurrency mode in "none", not "fixed".

What is the best way to face this? I mean that many times I do not want to control concurrency, only apply always the last modification. In example, I have a table with users, and a field is the phone number. I always want set the phone that I am trying to update, independent of if other user modify the register between my request and my update. If other user change the data, I overwrite it with my update.

In this case I don't see the problem, I am trying to delete a register that not exists in the database, it is what I want, that the register is not in the database. I could understand the problem in updates, if I trying to modify information that have been modify by other user, but in a delete operation...

Comment: MSDN even says: "*The `DeleteObject` method can be called on objects that are already deleted.*" (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.deleteobject.aspx)

Comment: In the first example of the link, I see that the first step is to create an entityKey, but it is needed to get the register from the database, but if I am not wrong, this requires an extra query to the database, and I would like to do only the minimum needed queries, for performance reasons. However, the problem perhaps is not be solved, because if other delete the register, I would be in the same situation. However, I will test it. Thanks.

Comment: Shouldn't you simply catch exceptions when SQL Server raises them !?